# Normal Probability Plots in Excel

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution

I am a student in an introductory statistics course and I am working on my project regarding number of hours I spend working my job a day. We went over normal probability plots and I am now trying to build one for my data in excel. Could someone walk me through how to do it? I tried to YouTube, but I have so many repeated values that I am confused about whether I can even use a normal probability plot.

This is the data I have(each value is the number of hours I spent daily on an activity):

1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7